# NSCache behaviour with non-object types

Tags: swift, nscache

The following code works perfectly well, but I am surprised, because I thought `NSCache` would require object keys & values, and would not take `CGFloat`s. Can someone explain to me what is happening?

```
class A
    var cachedPoints = NSCache()

    func rAt(theta theta: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {        
        if let r = self.cachedPoints.objectForKey(theta) as? CGFloat {
            return r
        }
        // do some very expensive maths here...
        let r = self.veryExpensiveFunction(theta)
        self.cachedPoints.setObject(r, forKey: theta)
        return r
    }
}
```

Comment: You mention CGPoint in the question, but that does not occur in the code. Did you mean CGFloat?

Comment: Oops, yes. Will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Working with Cocoa Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html) in the
"Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" documentation:

> **Numbers**
>
> Swift automatically bridges certain native number types, such as `Int`
>   and `Float`, to `NSNumber`.
>   ...
>   It also allows you to pass a value of type `Int`, for example, to an argument expecting an `NSNumber`.

The documentation mentions `Int`, `UInt`, `Float`, `Double`, `Bool`
as types which are automatically bridged to `NSNumber`, but apparently
this works for `CGFloat` as well (if "Foundation" is imported).
So in

```
self.cachedPoints.setObject(r, forKey: theta)
```

both `r` and `theta` are wrapped into `NSNumber` instances
and then passed to the `setObject()` method which takes two parameters
of type `AnyObject`.

There is also a bridging in the reverse direction, but that is
less well documented (or I could not find it). You can cast an
instance of `NSNumber` to `CGFloat` (or `Int`, `Float`, ...)

```
let num : NSNumber = ...
let x = num as CGFloat
```

and the result is the same as if you called `doubleValue` (or `floatValue`, depending on the architecture) on the number instance.
In

```
let obj : AnyObject = ...
let y = obj as? CGFloat // CGFloat?
```

the object is optionally cast to `NSNumber` and – if that was successful
– converted to `CGFloat` as in the previous example.

And that is what happens in

```
if let r = self.cachedPoints.objectForKey(theta) as? CGFloat { ... }
```

If the return value from `objectForKey()` is an `NSNumber` then
it is converted to `CGFloat` and assigned to `r`. Otherwise,
the optional binding fails.

Comment: Many thanks! I had originally used NSNumber, but it looked so clunky compared to `Dictionary` usage I just decided to try. Looks like I need to re-read the books again!